# Trigger a jenkins build based on update of specific folder inside git repository branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to find a solution for triggering a jenkins build based on update of specific folder inside git repository of a branch. My git repository root directory has a folder called "changers" . So if I change anything inside folder "changers" . I need to trigger the build.

Note that I am using multibranch pipeline.

Also I have tried with "changeset" option in jenkins to be use at groovy code. But it didn't work for me.

Thanks

Comment: Let's say you succeeded in triggering your build but your build failed. Should a next (unrelated to _that folder_) commit trigger your build again?

Comment: yes.. triggered the build for outside the changers at folder called "changers".

Comment: So maybe what you want is to know whether there is a difference for that folder _in this particular branch_ ?